# m2e Maven Build war:war produces FileNotFoundException for \target\classes

Tags: maven, build, war, filenotfoundexception, m2e

I'm running Eclipse Kepler on Windows 7 with the included m2e-wtp tools.
My Dynamic Web Project references another project, and I am using a dependency in the pom file to link to the project.
My code complies and runs fine in Eclipse, and I can use Eclipse Export > war to export a war file, which also runs fine  and includes the other project. However, I would like to use Maven to produce the war, and then later use the Maven Tomcat plugin and Maven release plugin.

To run the Maven war I select the main project, right click and select Run as... Maven Build, set the goal as war:war and then select the check-box Resolve Workspace artifacts. I also select the Debug Output option.

The build fails, and looking at the stack trace, I see the following error is the root of the problem:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Projects\WebDocs\EclipseProjects\shared\target\classes (Access is denied)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
```

I've checked that the target\classes folder exists and that it has the correct security access (at this point, I've given all users full control). 
I've tried the latest Tomcat plugin and get a similar error.

Does anyone have any ideas how to fix or work around this?

Comment: Does your build work on command line (not from Eclipse) just via dos bos in Windows? `mvn clean package`?

Comment: Thanks @khmarbaise.  The mvn clean package command from the command line fails. But I believe it is because, unlike m2e, it does not know how to resolve workspace artifacts. Here is the error:

    `[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
c:\Projects\WebDocs\EclipseProjects\myproject\webdproj>`

Comment: Please show the full pom file and the full stack trace not only excerpts.